# How to detect whether the "res.end()" is called or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a api to detect whether the `res.end` is called?

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  some_function_may_called_end(req, res);

  // Is there a api like below?
  if(res.is_ended == true) {
     //...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check [`res.headersSent` flag](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_headerssent). It'll work for most cases.

The only case when it won't work as you want is when you're calling [`res.writeHead` method](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_reasonphrase_headers) manually bebore calling `some_function_may_called_end` function, but I can hardly imagine a situation when you'll do so.